# scala load json data from postgres sql into the domain object error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: postgresql, scala, doobie

I am writing scala code to load data from db (postgres) using following sql.

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    a.act_type_id AS actTypeId
    COALESCE(json_agg(x.procedure_id), '[]'::json)  as actProcIds
FROM
    act a
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            act_procedure p
        WHERE
            p.procedure_id IN (?, ?)
    ) x ON a.id = x.act_id
WHERE
    (a.act_type_id = ?)
GROUP BY
    a.id
ORDER BY
    a.id ASC
LIMIT
    10
```

and I got result below:

```
id                                  |acttypeid                           |actprocids
------------------------------------+------------------------------------+----------------------------------------
e33681a3-7d1a-4f7b-af32-b9ad59f55052|84bc042c-155c-40ef-88ca-6b0be127d87c|["aa5b40f6-0e83-4680-9ce6-76cf1b3b80c9"]
```

The domain file is

```
case class ActProcedureDomain(
    id: FUUID,
    actTypeId: Option[FUUID],
    actProcIds: List[FUUID]
)
```

Below is the code to call the sql

```
def getPaginatedList(param: ListInput[Q])(implicit sync: Sync[F]): EitherT[F, MyCustomizedError, ListOutput[O]] = {
    val result = EitherT(
      param.xNextToken
        .flatMap(token => {
          if (token.queryParamHash == param.queryParams.hashCode()) None
          else QueryParamsConflictError("Prev params and current version do not match.", encode(token)).some
        }).fold(
        paginate(param, xa)
          .leftSemiflatMap(error =>
            logAndReturn(RepositoryError(s"Issue retrieving paginated list based on params=$param: ${error.getMessage}")))
          .value
      )(error => logAndReturn(error).map(Left[MyCustomizedError, ListOutput[O]])))
    val res = result.andLogIfSlow("getPaginatedList")
    println("yyy ->")
    res
  }
```

And I can see "yyy ->" was printed in the log. Howeve, I can not see the log after this. For instance,

entity           <- repository.getPaginatedList(input)
_               = println("zzz -> ")

above doesn't print "zzz ->" in log. But I did see the error below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 40
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.buildArrayList(PgArray.java:449)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getArrayImpl(PgArray.java:167)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgArray.getArray(PgArray.java:127)
    at doobie.util.Get$Advanced$.$anonfun$array$1(get.scala:145)
    at doobie.util.Get$Advanced$.$anonfun$array$1$adapted(get.scala:143)
    at doobie.util.Get.unsafeGetNullable(get.scala:37)
    at doobie.util.Read$.$anonfun$fromGetOption$1(read.scala:78)
    at doobie.util.Read$.$anonfun$fromGetOption$1$adapted(read.scala:78)
    at doobie.util.Read.$anonfun$map$1(read.scala:51)
    at doobie.util.Read.$anonfun$map$1$adapted(read.scala:51)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1$adapted(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1$adapted(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1$adapted(read.scala:99)
    at doobie.util.LowerPriorityRead.$anonfun$product$1(read.scala:99)
    ...
```

That makes me believe that the loading that json data into the List attribute of the domain object gives e trouble.

By checking online, I then import following class into my repository file (only import it but not use the actProcsMeta in any way), but it didn't solve the issue.

```
object ActsDoobieMeta {

  implicit val actProcsMeta: Meta[List[FUUID]] =
    Meta[Json].imap(json => json.as[List[FUUID]].getOrElse(List()))(procs => proc.asJson)
}
```

Can anyone please help here? Thanks in advance.